# warning : syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '3B' in line 2 of <stdin> splits into two tokens

Tags: python, json, tree, graphviz

I am trying to run this python file. The output is coming as such - see the attached screenshot. When I am using this command `python tree_to_graph.py | dot -Tpng -otree.png` to get the graph, I am getting this warning as mentioned in the title. Please see below for the screenshots.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import sys


# Tree in JSON format
#s = '{"Harry": {"children": ["Bill", {"Jane": {"children": [{"Diane": {"children": ["Mary"]}}, "Mark"]}}]}}'
s = '{"Harry": {"children": ["3Bi_ll<=0.5 samplesize=10", {"Jane": {"children": [{"Diane": {"children": ["Mary"]}}, "Mark"]}}]}}'
#{'pd_a6 <= 2.5':
# Convert JSON tree to a Python dict
data = json.loads(s)

# Convert back to JSON & print to stderr so we can verify that the tree is correct.
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4), file=sys.stderr)

# Extract tree edges from the dict
edges = []

def get_edges(treedict, parent=None):
    name = next(iter(treedict.keys()))
    if parent is not None:
        edges.append((parent, name))
    for item in treedict[name]["children"]:
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            get_edges(item, parent=name)
        else:
            edges.append((name, item))

get_edges(data)

# Dump edge list in Graphviz DOT format
print('strict digraph tree {')
for row in edges:
    print('    {0} -> {1};'.format(*row))
print('}')
```

[image: output]
[image: output]

Comment: What is the intention of `3Bi_ll<=0.5`?

Comment: the name is as such : 3Bi_ll

Comment: The name of what, looks to me more some attempt to do some settings. The other names look all names of persons, see also the output that is fed into `dot`.

Comment: `<=0.5 samplesize=10` doesn't look like Graphviz syntax. If you mean that the whole node should be named "3Bi_11<=0.5 samplesize=10", which is a bad idea — use labels for that, but if you really want that, you will have to take it into double quotes: `Harry -> "3Bi_11<=0.5 samplesize=10"`

Comment: I had the same problem. It was because `<` is a reserved html character and my drawing was making a html table. Check if graphviz is using html at all.